# UIPopover crashing from UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I'm presenting a UIPopover from a UIButton but my app is crashing at line `[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button bounds] inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:NO];`

```
- (IBAction)birthdayButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 344)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300);

    [popoverView addSubview:self.view];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];        
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;

    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 244);

    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button bounds] inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:NO];

    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to add self.view as subview. UIView object can be displayed only once in every current mooment, you cannot show popover with content as self.view in self.view. If you really need to perform this task then try to make copy of required views.

Answer (score 0):

Change the inView to self.view. inView means in which UIView you want to present popover.

```
presentPopoverFromRect:[button bounds] inView:**self.view** permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:NO];
```